# Usage of “in-tray”

Tags: meaning-in-context

A recent CNBC.com article reads:

> Britain’s new Prime Minister Rishi Sunak is set to assume office Tuesday and, with it, ***one of the most daunting political in-trays in modern British history*** as he attempts to steer the country through an existing cost-of-living crisis, political and social disjuncture, and a looming recession.

I understand that an in tray is a tray where you can find all mails
received  that are still  to be dealt with.

In the above article “in-trays”
is used as a synonym of “difficult issues”.

Is this metaphor a common usage? Or is it just a one-off usage?

Comment: Why do you think "in tray" is synonymous with "difficult issues"? You can find a lot of examples of its use [in Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-tray). Politicians tend not to get many letters saying, "Dear Prime Minister, I'm very happy!" but that might be different for other people who get good news.

Comment: It has the same metaphoric significance as _To-Do List_.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a false premise. An intrusion may contain many things, including but not restricted to bad.

Answer (score 4):

Common usage. He’s got a lot in his in box. There’s also a saying that “you can’t manage out of your in box,”

In box and in tray are the same thing.

He’s got a lot on his plate also says the same thing.

Comment: Yes, but do in box, in tray etc have a negative connotation? Do they imply difficult issues to deal with  or are they generic?

Comment: _In-tray_ (rather than _box_) is usual in British English. It just means 'stuff to be dealt with' - _daunting_ gives the negative sense.